# VBA Date and Currency conditions to copy and paste data to added sheets named by Date and Currency

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my challenge. I try to copy and paste data based on Currency and Dates to a newly created Worksheets in the same Workbook. Each newly created Worksheet should be named by Currency and Date from the main source. I am stuck with dates and I am not sure how to add other currencies. Please advise. Thank you very much.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Create_Copy_of_JE_DATA_Split_By_Currency_AND_By_Date()

    Dim draft As Worksheet
    Dim curr_date As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow
    Dim LastColumn As Integer
    Dim i
    Dim drafttable As Object
    Dim Curr As String
    Dim transdate As Date

    'Clean up previous data before start the macro
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each i In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If i.name = "Draft_Data" Then i.Delete
    Next i

    For Each i In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If i.name = "Currency_Date" Then i.Delete
    Next i


    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


    'Create a draft sheet to work with data
    Sheets("JE_data").Select
    Sheets("JE_data").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.count)

    ActiveSheet.name = "Draft_Data"

    Set draft = Sheets("Draft_Data")

    LastRow = draft.Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp).Row

    LastColumn = draft.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column


    'Copy Currency and Date data to find unique data
    'It depends on your data structure, the original assumption was that column C is currency and column D is transaction Date
    'The actual data structure is different - Currency is Column "P" and Date is Column "W",
    'so I would have to delete Columns between them

    Range("P2:W" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.count)
    ActiveSheet.name = "Currency_Date"

    Set curr_date = Sheets("Currency_Date")

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    With Sheets("Currency_Date")

        .Columns("B:G").EntireColumn.Delete
        .Range("$A$1:$B$" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo
        
    End With

    'ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo

    'Select Draft sheet and start filtering
    draft.Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$W$" & LastRow), , xlYes).name = "Draft_table"

    'so when I filter it, it will have the same format.
    'it's upto you to choose the date format, :) I'm in Australia so I choose d/mm/yyyy
    Columns("W:W").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "d/mm/yyyy;@"

    Set drafttable = draft.ListObjects("Draft_table")


    'The idea is for each unique value of currency and date pair, we will filter this Draft 'table
    'and copy the result to a new sheet then rename this sheet.
    For i = 1 To Sheets("Currency_Date").Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp).Row
        Curr = curr_date.Range("A" & i).Value
        transdate = curr_date.Range("B" & i).Value

        draft.Select

        drafttable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=Curr
        drafttable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=23, Criteria1:=transdate

        drafttable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=23, Criteria1:="=" & transdate, Operator:=xlAnd


        Range("Draft_table").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

        Selection.Copy
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.count)
        Range("A2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        ActiveSheet.name = Format(transdate, "MMM DD YYYY") & " " & Curr

        Sheets("JE_Data").Select
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets(Format(transdate, "MMM DD YYYY") & " " & Curr).Select
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False

        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

        'Prepare for next filter.
        draft.ShowAllData
    Next i

    'draft.Delete
    'curr_date.Delete

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your data look like, so I use a simple data like below:

```
ID  Name    Currency    Transaction_Date
1   A       AUD         1/08/2014
2   B       USD         2/08/2014
3   C       GBP         4/08/2014
4   D       JPY         10/09/2014
5   E       AUD         4/08/2014
6   F       USD         10/09/2014
7   A       GBP         1/08/2014
8   B       JPY         2/08/2014
9   C       AUD         4/08/2014
10  D       USD         10/09/2014
```

My idea is create a list of unique value (Currency,Transaction date), then using filter to get data with 2 criterial: Currency and Data. Doesn't matter how many rows you have, it should work the same.

Copy the filtered data to new sheet and rename this sheet to DATE & Currency as required.

When I test, this works perfectly

*(I have not clean my code yet, so please modify it as you need)*

```vb
Sub Create_Copy_of_JEDATA()

Dim draft, curr_date As Worksheet
Dim LastRow, LastColumn As Integer

'Clean up previous data before start the macro
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each i In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If i.Name = "Draft_Data" Then i.Delete
    Next i

    For Each i In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If i.Name = "Currency_Date" Then i.Delete
    Next i


    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


'Create a draft sheet to work with data
    Sheets("JE_data").Select
    Sheets("JE_data").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    ActiveSheet.Name = "Draft_Data"

    Set draft = Sheets("Draft_Data")

    LastRow = draft.Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp).Row

    LastColumn = draft.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column



'Copy Currency and Date data to find unique data
'Depend on your data structure, I assume that column C is currency and column D is transaction Date
    Range("C2:D" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Currency_Date"

    Set curr_date = Sheets("Currency_Date")

    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo

'Select Draft sheet and start filtering
    draft.Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$D$" & LastRow), , xlYes).Name = "Draft_table"

    'so when I filter it, it will have the same format.
    'it's upto you to choose the date format, :) I'm in Australia so I choose d/mm/yyyy
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "d/mm/yyyy;@"

    Set DraftTable = draft.ListObjects("Draft_table")


    'The idea is for each unique value of currency and date pair, we will filter this Draft table
    'and copy the result to a new sheet then rename this sheet.
    For i = 1 To Sheets("Currency_Date").Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp).Row
        Curr = curr_date.Range("A" & i).Value
        transdate = curr_date.Range("B" & i).Value

        draft.Select

        DraftTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Curr

        DraftTable.Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=" & transdate, Operator:=xlAnd


        Range("Draft_table").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

        Selection.Copy
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Range("A2").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        ActiveSheet.Name = Format(transdate, "MMM DD YYYY") & " " & Curr

        Sheets("JE_Data").Select
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets(Format(transdate, "MMM DD YYYY") & " " & Curr).Select
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False

        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

        'Prepare for next filter.
        draft.ShowAllData
    Next i

'draft.Delete
'curr_date.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Harry,thank you for kind help. There is an error: variable ("i") is not defined. Should it be a String/Range/Other? Thank you

Comment: Hi but i is an iterate variable just for the loop, do you get an error from it? variable "i" was assigned for many type of data in my code, include object, integer..... Did you use Option Explicit in your code?

Comment: Hi Harry, yes, I have Option Explicit at the top of the Module. I didn't test it further as I was stuck right at the beginning. Most likely it would complain about not declared variable in other cases as well. I will declare i as integer and see what happens.

Comment: How about you just comment the option explicit and test the code first

Comment: Ok, it you want to keep Option Explicit then there are a few things need to be updated: (I can't jump to next line in this comment so please use each DIM in one line) Please add
Dim i 
Dim drafttable As Object 
Dim Curr As String 
Dim transdate As Date

Comment: Hi Harry, it goes through the code and creates additional sheets. I have to change the range as it is actually from "A" to "W". Also currency is in column "P" (number of column 16) and  date is in column "W" (number of column 23). I will keep you posted. Thank you!!!

Comment: No just Dim i and dont specify its type

Comment: OK, thank you for the clarification, I added all variables. Let's try it

Comment: I am in Canada, so the date format is OK. I have issue with your assumption regarding removing duplicated Currency. I only want to get the duplicated currency removed if it belongs to the same date. If it refers to a different date, then I have to keep it a the spot rate would be different. How can I solve it? It should be a condition based on a date. Then it should be checking if there is another currency and repeat the process...Any thoughts?

Comment: because the code will highlight 2 column: Currency and Data before it starts removing the duplicated value, so it will works as you expected

Comment: Yes, it works!!! Thank you so much , Harry!!! I have made a few minor changes in ranges and it is OK if I run it separately. Anyway I have an integration issue when I am calling this macro from a Consolidated Procedure. It stops at ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo . I tried to state explicitly the name of worksheet but it didn't help. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure what is in your Consolidated Procedure, so I can't replicated your error. What does it say?

Comment: Hi Harry!!! I forgot my mobile hard drive at home. Sorry...Error message: Run-time error '5': Invalid Procedure call or argument. If I publish the working code will it help you recreate an error? Thank you

Comment: I found 1 possible reason. I have set up "Option Base 1" at the top of my Module which helps to deal with arrays in one of the prior Subs. Other than that everything is the same (Option Explicit as well). Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: I have edited my original post with the working Code. It works from a separate Module with Option Explicit but it gives me run-time error '5' on line ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo with Option Explicit and Option Base 1. I tried to play with Array by changing numbers (e.g. 0,1) or (2,3) but it didn't help. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi Harry. Thank you so much for great help!!! Here is a suggested solution: I call this macro from another module with different settings at the top of the module:  'There is a run-time error '5'on line "ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$" & LastRow).
    'RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo" with Option Explicit and Option Base 1
    'in Module1.I have to call this Macro from another module (2) which doesn't have this settings.
    
    Call Module2.Create_Copy_of_JE_DATA_Split_By_Currency_AND_By_Date

Comment: Hi @Russ1969, sorry I didn't open stackoverflow site on weeekend. But it's good that you have found a working solution :) Cheer!

Comment: No problem, Harry. I appreciate your help. Yes, it is working.Take care, Russ